# File transfer over specific network

Tags: network-shares, gigabit-ethernet

I have 5 machines running Windows 7 32-bit, and 2 machines running Windows XP SP3 32-bit. I use workgroups, not a domain. I have Simple File Sharing enabled. All the machines have Gigabit NICs, with properly cabled CAT 6 cables over a short distance, all connected to a Gigabit switch. All these machines use static IP addresses, and are connected to the Internet (50/50Mb FiOS) via 10/100 router (which I can't change).

If the Internet router is disconnected, Simple File Sharing between any machine moves at Gb speeds, but if the Internet is connected, speeds drop by a factor of 3 or 4, always under 10Mb. Remove Internet connection, speeds jump back up, limited only by the machine's capability.

So I put second Gigabit NICs in each machine, linked with a Gigabit switch. Traffic between machines will not use this second network unless disconnected from first network.

Network 1 - 192.168.1.xxx (connects to 10/100 Internet router)
Network 2 - 10.0.1.xxx (all devices on network are Gigabit)

What can I do to direct traffic between machines to flow through 2nd network, which is not speed limited by 10/100 device? I rather like the idea of a second network, as file transfers do not clutter up the Internet side. All machines must be Internet connected.

Managed switch? Netmasking? VPN? If necessary, I can change any IP address, including the Internet router. I'm still stymied by Netmasking.

Answer (score 1):

If you know you aren't going to get more systems, you can set up HOSTS files for each one, or share via the `\\10.0.1.xxx` address. I'll start with hosts.

If you open **Notepad (as an Administrator)**, and edit the `%windir%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` `and %windir%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` files, you can add in the hosts as such:

```
10.0.1.2    Host1
10.0.1.3    Host2
10.0.1.4    Host3
...
10.0.1.15   Host14
```

Save the files, and reboot the computer. Now, if you ping Host1, you get a result from 10.0.1.2, over the Gigabit network.

### Drawbacks:

- If you change a machine name, it won't take effect unless you edit this file.
- If you make changes (such as adding another PC), you need to edit these files on all the machines.

The second option is to use file sharing based off their IP address. For example, `net use z: \\10.0.1.2\SharedFolder /persistent:yes`. If you know the IP addresses, this may work for you. There is no maintenance on each computer, as long as you keep those static IP addresses.

For reference, when a computer tries to determine which interface to use, it checks the Routes to determine where to send it. Check out the `route` command under the command prompt. If you type `route print -4`, it will list the IPv4 ranges it knows about, and what gateway it will use to communicate with those hosts.